# ng-sortable on a Table. When I drag a row, the CSS gets thrown off

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm using this library here: [ng-sortable](https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable)

And I'm using it on a table.  The thing is, when I physically drag a table row, the row shrinks and doesn't keep the original look of the table.  I narrowed it down to this section of the CSS:

```
.as-sortable-drag {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

I tried removing that completely but then the row itself actually just disappears until i set the row down.

Is there any way I can get the row to keep it's shape and look?

```
<tbody as-sortable ng-model="headline.contents.lines">
<tr ng-repeat="line in headline.contents.lines" as-sortable-item style="cursor: move">
    <td as-sortable-item-handle>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
    <td as-sortable-item-handle ng-show="statsSelected === 2 || statsSelected === 'twostats'">{{ line.stat1 }}</td>
    <td as-sortable-item-handle>{{ line.label }}</td>
    <td as-sortable-item-handle ng-show="statsSelected === 1 || statsSelected === 'onestat'">{{ line.stat1 }}</td>
    <td as-sortable-item-handle ng-show="statsSelected === 2 || statsSelected === 'twostats'">{{ line.stat2 }}</td>
    <td as-sortable-item-handle><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Well you'll need to examine which of those ng-sortable CSS styles is affecting the other styles on the row. You can do this without dragging by simply opening your Dev Tools, and adding those ng-sortable styles inline to the row, and see what happens. Then you can add styles to your original style sheet to prevent that change. Can you show us all the styles affecting the row?

Comment: Can you replicate this in a Plunker? Would be much easier to help.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  Having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

CSS styling may be applied via the "as-sortable-dragging" class
When the "as-sortable-item" is being dragged, the CSS class "as-sortable-dragging" is added to all elements. e.g. in HTML    ```

in CSS .as-sortable-dragging{ border: 1px dotted #000 !important; }